# How to avoid null checking before foreach IList

Tags: c#, null-check

I have the following code:

```
IList<object> testList = null;

... 

if (testList != null) // <- how to get rid of this check?
{
   foreach (var item in testList)
   {
       //Do stuff.
   }
}
```

Is there a way to *avoid* the `if` before the `foreach`? I saw a few solutions but when using `List`, is there any solution when using `IList`?

Comment: Do you mean `if(testList != null)`

Comment: Ensure `testList` is initialised.

Comment: `foreach (var item in testList ?? new List<object>()) {...}`

Comment: why do you care? If there's a possibility it might be null, then you need to check. Not a big deal really. As Dmitry shows, you can cheat by initialising as an empty list of objects, which means it won't loop, but to me it seems pointless to initialise something in memory just to save a line of code

Comment: fubo yes, my mistake.
DmitryBychenko I think this will work, thanks!

Answer (score 12, accepted):

Well, you can try `??` operator:

```
testList ?? Enumerable.Empty<object>()
```

we get either `testList` itself or an empty `IEnumerable<object>`:

```
IList<object> testList = null;

...

// Or ?? new object[0] - whatever empty collection implementing IEnumerable<object>
foreach (var item in testList ?? Enumerable.Empty<object>())
{
    //Do stuff.
}
```

Answer (score 7):

Try this

```
IList<object> items = null;
items?.ForEach(item =>
{
  // ...
});
```

Answer (score 3):

you can create extention method like this :

```
public static IList<T> OrEmptyIfNull<T>(this IList<T> source)
 {
       return source ?? Enumerable.Empty<T>().ToList();
 }
```

Then you can write:

```
 foreach (var item in testList.OrEmptyIfNull())
    {
    }
```

Answer (score 2):

I stole the following extension method from a Project:

```
public static IEnumerable<T> NotNull<T>(this IEnumerable<T> list)
{
    return list ?? Enumerable.Empty<T>();
}
```

Then use conveniently like this

```
foreach (var item in myList.NotNull())
{

}
```